# Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Class/MethodBody [OK]

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  EditText edit1;
  EditText edit2;
  TextView tvRes;
  Button btnSum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
  edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
  btnSum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSum);
  tvRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRes);

  btnSum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
  @Override

   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    try
    {
     String s1 = edit1.getText().toString();
     String s2 = edit2.getText().toString();
     double res =
     Double.parseDouble(s1)+Double.parseDouble(s2);
     String s3 = String.format(s1+" + " +s2+ " =  "+ "%.3f",res);
     tvRes.setText(s3);
    }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Введены некорректные числа", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      tvRes.setText("");
     }
    }
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код по-нормальному лесенкой и всё станет понятно

Comment: @andreymal а есть такая опция в эклипсе?

Comment: @DarkHat, есть, откройте файл с кодом, и жмите Ctrl+Shift+F, и код волшебный образом отформатируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самую последнюю........................................После..});

Comment: И не одну }, а две.